# Android Design Support TabLayout overlapping content

Tags: android, layout, tabs, android-toolbar, androiddesignsupport

I am using the new TabLayout introduced in the design support library. I have the code like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/lines_coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="4dp"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is, that the tabs overlap the top of the content the fragments display. How can I fix this? I am using the TabLayout like in the examples on Github, so I believe there is no issue with my code. I already have a Toolbar because I use the tabs in a fragment in a navigation drawer, so I removed it from the AppBarLayout.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to your `ViewPager`: this is what changes the height of the View to be below the `AppBarLayout` rather than the full `match_parent` height.