# In a Tabbed Activity with ViewPager, the ListView appears cut from the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-layout-weight

I have a Tabbed Activity with three ListView Fragments but the ListView appears cut from the buttom. You never see the last element.

[image: screenshoot]

I tried everything but I'm not able to solve it.

This is the Tabbed Activity:

```
public class TabbedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private String query_id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        query_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("query_id");
        String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        setTitle(title);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return AFragment.newInstance(0, "A", query_id);
                case 1:
                    return BFragment.newInstance(1, "B", query_id);
                case 2:
                    return CFragment.newInstance(2, "C", query_id);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "A";
                case 1:
                    return "B";
                case 2:
                    return "C";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Tabbed Activity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.domain.app.TabbedActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Inside the ViewPager, I load ListView Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: use recycle-view instead

Comment: It looks like that you are not setting the `supportActionBar` to the `Toolbar` you are using in `xml`, please show whether you are doing this or not?

Comment: @MustansarSaeed yes, I'm using it: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Comment: Please show us your `Activity` code because in the design you shared , `ActionBar` and `ToolBar` both exists

Comment: @MustansarSaeed I've added de code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Tabbed Activity Bottom off Screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920513/android-tabbed-activity-bottom-off-screen)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this design will help in what you need, add:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.domain.app.TabbedActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Notas: It has been deleted `android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"` to do the tests.

Comment: Thanks @Angel :) I have been looking for the solution from many days :)

Answer (score 1):

With a ListView in android 5.0 > you can achieve your needs by using a `CoordinatorLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout` and add     `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` inside your  `ListView`.  Your final Layout should look like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    >
</ListView>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout/>
```

For older Devices use RecyclerView instead of ListView

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that is normal as you can see in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30675037/4409113

It should be fixed with adding:

`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

to your `ViewPager` which you already have it.

> You never see the last element.

Perhaps you will have to use that inside the `NestedScrollView`.

Similar question: [Android Tabbed Activity Bottom off Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920513/android-tabbed-activity-bottom-off-screen)